# How to update the apple passes create without webServiceURL

Tags: apple-wallet, pkpass

Earlier, I had created some Apple pass without 'webServiceURL' using PHP.
Those pass were added in the Apple wallet successfully,
Now. I need to update the existing those passes.
Are there options to update those existing passes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are no options to update a pass if you do not set the `webServiceURL` in the original pass. Also, if you unset the `webServiceURL` in the updated pass, it will cease to be available for update.

Apple uses "silent push" to prompt the device to send an HTTP request when a pass is updated. If you do not have the device id to send with your APNS push request, which you get from setting `webServiceURL` in the pass.json in the original pass, then you cannot prompt an update.